# Find Content inside () after a string

Tags: regex

I found something to go on with but couldnt solve it.
What I need is a regex that machtes inside () like 
`(?<=\()[^]]+(?=\))` that works with any text and gets me exakt the content inside the ().

But I have something like this:

> *Empfänger: Besteller, Test (**Ahoy**)*

And *Empfänger:* is always same, but *Besteller, Test* can change.
 
How I mach still just the content inside the ()?

Inside the look behind i couldnt work with * or +.

Thanks
Oli

Comment: Perhaps, `Empfänger: .* \((.*?)\)` and grab Group 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need something simple like:

```
Empfänger:.*\(([^)]+)\)
```

That will capture the whatever is between the first ( up to the next )  It's using a character class.

You can see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/3LhvOD/1

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other regex and it didn't work, So I generated this for your usage:

```
(?:\((.*)\))
```

It allows anything in between, and leaves out the brackets from the match! :)